# getting same error on 404 htaccess for only one word

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to rewrite custom urls to navigate in one website using like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ page.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

To know what I get the page.php is starting with print_r($_GET); only for know what I get.

The point is when the url is as follow I get different results:
http://www.demowebsite.com/contact/
The result is a 404 error

but if you use the following URL:
http://www.demowebsite.com/contact-bla-bla/
The result is  page => "conctact-bla-bla"

I restarded wampp, close the web browser and always getting that error on "contact" term, and for everthing else that just works fine.

Thank you for any advice you have.

Comment: Is there a directory called "contact"?

Comment: No, there is no directory called "contact"

Comment: Is there any other rule or is there any other .htaccess?

Comment: `Options All -Indexes`
Thats all I have, this is in the first line